# GPU usage per process on a Linux machine (CUDA)

Tags: monitoring, gpu

I use the CUDA toolkit to perform some computations on my Nvidia GPUs. How can I see the per-process GPU usage on a Linux machine (CUDA)?

`nvidia-smi` does list all processes for each GPU, but doesn't indicate the GPU utilization per process:

[image]

Comment: I haven't found any solution so far.

Comment: So I am still interested if someone has any idea.

Answer (score 13):

I stumbled upon the following:

`watch -n 0.5 nvidia-smi pmon -c 1`

Though it seems to have a different measure of GPU usage than the volatility metric in the usual `nvidia-smi`.

Full options in the [manual](https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/DCGM/docs/nvidia-smi-367.38.pdf).